# Nesting and referencing xml file with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

First of all, I am very new to xml world. I am facing problem to extract data from a cross-referenced xml file. Following is an example (modified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Student info and students enrollment --> 
<StudentList>
    <Student_info>
    <Student id = "1">
        <Name>Mike</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="2">
        <Name>Matteo</Name>
        <Age>15</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="3">
        <Name>Matt</Name>
        <Age>17</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="4"> 
        <Name>Siri</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="5">
       <Name>Sara</Name>
       <Age>15</Age>
       </Student> 
    </Student_info>

    <Course_info>
       <Course id="PHY101">
            <Title>Physics Fundamentals></Title>
            <!-- Reference of the students enrolled in physics course -->
            <Student refid ="1"/>
            <Student refid = "2"/>
            <Student refid = "5"/>
        </Course>

    <Course id = "MATH101">
        <Title>Mathematics Basics</Title>
        <!-- Reference of the students enrolled in mathematics course -->
        <Student refid = "2"/>
        <Student refid = "3"/>
        <Student refid = "4"/> 
    </Course>
    </Course_info>
</StudentList>
```

Now, I would like to get the following output using java:

```
Course Title: Physics Fundamentals
Name of the enrolled students = Mike, Matteo and Sara
```

And the same for the other course. How can I do that efficiently using **java**? My main question is to how to extract information from a cross-referenced element (such as **Student refid ="1"** in the example)?

**An solution that I have found:**

Firstly the xml file should be modified as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Student info and students enrollment --> 
<StudentList>
    <Student_info>
    <Student id = "1">
        <Name>Mike</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="2">
        <Name>Matteo</Name>
        <Age>15</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="3">
        <Name>Matt</Name>
        <Age>17</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="4"> 
        <Name>Siri</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="5">
       <Name>Sara</Name>
       <Age>15</Age>
       </Student> 
    </Student_info>

    <Course_info>
       <Course id="PHY101">
            <Title>Physics Fundamentals></Title>
            <!-- Reference of the students enrolled in physics course -->
            <!-- Make change here -->
            <Student>1</Student>
            <Student>2</Student>
            <Student>5</Student>
        </Course>

    <Course id = "MATH101">
        <Title>Mathematics Basics</Title>
        <!-- Reference of the students enrolled in mathematics course -->
        **<!-- Make change here -->**
        <Student>3</Student>
        <Student>4</Student>    
    </Course>
    </Course_info>
</StudentList>
```

Now, Student class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student
{

    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlID
    private String id;


    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Course class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlIDREF;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Course")
    class Course
    {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "cid")
        String id;
        @XmlElement(name = "Title")
        String Title;

        @XmlElement(name="Student")
        @XmlIDREF
        List<Student> student;

        Course(){
            student = new ArrayList<Student>();
        }

        String getID()
        {
            return id;
        }

        String getTitle()
        {
            return Title;
        }

        void setID(String id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        void setTitle(String title)
        {
            this.Title = title;
        }


        List<Student> getStudent()
        {
            return student;
        }

        void setStudents(List<Student> student)
        {
            this.student = student;
        }



 }
```

StudentList class:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "StudentList")
public class StudentList
{

    private List<Student> Student_info;
    private List<Course> Course_info;

    @XmlElement(name = "Student")
    public List<Student> getStudent_info()
    {
        return Student_info;
    }

    public void setStudent_info(List<Student> Student_info)
    {
        this.Student_info = Student_info;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Course")
    public List<Course> getCourse_Info()
    {
        return Course_info;
    }

    public void setCourse_Info(List<Course> Course_info)
    {
        this.Course_info = Course_info;
    }
}
```

TextXml class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    public class TextXml {
          public static void main(String[] args)
            {

                try
                {



                    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentList.class);
                    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

                    File xml = new File("NewFile.xml");
                    StudentList studentlist = (StudentList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

                    for (Course course: studentlist.getCourse_Info()){
                        System.out.println("Course Title: "+course.getTitle());
                        for(Student std: course.getStudent()){
                            System.out.print(std.getName()+" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                }
                catch (JAXBException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: please see my another solution it is working please vote up for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Student info and students enrollment --> 
<StudentList>
    <Student id = "1">
        <Name>Mike</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="2">
        <Name>Matteo</Name>
        <Age>15</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="3">
        <Name>Matt</Name>
        <Age>17</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="4"> 
        <Name>Siri</Name>
        <Age>16</Age>
    </Student>
    <Student id="5">
       <Name>Sara</Name>
       <Age>15</Age>
     </Student>
     <Course id="PHY101">
        <Title>Physics Fundamentals</Title>
        <!-- Reference of the students enrolled in physics course -->
            <Student refid ="1"/>
            <Student refid = "2"/>
     </Course>
     <Course id = "MATH101">
        <Title>Mathematics Basics</Title>
        <!-- Reference of the students enrolled in mathematics course -->
            <Student refid = "2"/>
            <Student refid = "3"/>
            <Student refid = "4"/> 
      </Course>
  </StudentList>
```

---

```
 package test;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Student
    {

        private String Name;
        private int Age;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
        private int id;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "refid")
        private int refid;

        public String getName()
        {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
            return Age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            Age = age;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getRefid()
        {
            return refid;
        }

        public void setRefid(int refid)
        {
            this.refid = refid;
        }

    }
```

---

```
     package test;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Course")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Course
    {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
        private String id;
        private String Title;
        @XmlElement(name = "Student")
        private List<Student> Students = null;

        public String getID()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle()
        {
            return Title;
        }

        public void setID(String id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            this.Title = title;
        }

        public List<Student> getStudents()
        {
            return Students;
        }

        public void setStudents(List<Student> Students)
        {
            this.Students = Students;
        }



 }
```

---

```
        package test;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "StudentList")
    public class StudentList
    {

        private List<Student> Student_info;
        private List<Course> Course_info;

        @XmlElement(name = "Student")
        public List<Student> getStudent_info()
        {
            return Student_info;
        }

        public void setStudent_info(List<Student> Student_info)
        {
            this.Student_info = Student_info;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "Course")
        public List<Course> getCourse_Info()
        {
            return Course_info;
        }

        public void setCourse_Info(List<Course> Course_info)
        {
            this.Course_info = Course_info;
        }
    }
```

---

```
  package test;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            File file = new File("D:\\xmlfile.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentList.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StudentList studentlist = (StudentList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            for (Student emp : studentlist.getStudent_info())
            {
                System.out.println(emp.getAge());
                System.out.println(emp.getName());
                System.out.println(emp.getId());
                System.out.println(emp.getRefid());
            }

        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tested the code? My code is returning an error.

Comment: have you changed the xml file path and xml format as mentioned above.please make your standalone java project with above files only then run the you will defiantly got the result. i have tested it .

Comment: I checked everything, essentially, there is no different between the xml file of your and mine. The error is not in the file path, its about "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/mahbub/workspace/EnergyPlanGUI/NewFile.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 7; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.]"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> Should be first line of your xml file so please remove any blank line or blank space above it.